# WPF TextBox does not update from bounded class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I'm currently stuck on how to update the text of my textbox whenever any class changes the text. Currently, only my main thread does so, and I have tried various methods (including a dispatch) to update the view from anywhere. My code looks like this:

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name ="textBoxResults" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

XAML.CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ConsoleLog cl { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWindow_Load();
            cl = new ConsoleLog();
            DataContext = cl;
        }
}
    private void ButtonBeginTests_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        new Thread(() =>
        {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>{
            tc = new TestController(.., .., cl); //other args not important
            tc.beginTest();
        }));
        }).Start();
    }
```

ConsoleLog Class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test_DesktopApplication.src
{
    public class ConsoleLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void addToLog(string text)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { this.Text += text; }));
        }
}
```

A class calls "addToLog" multiple times during a separate thread of background processes. Any indication to what I could be doing wrong?

EDIT: I can *actually* get this to work by using this after every addToLog call:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
```

however I don't know if this is a "good" fix.

EDIT 2:

I have updated the MainWindow class to show when this class is called, the class that calls the log is below:

```
public class Testcontroller
{

ConsoleLog cl;

public GEN2TestController(.., .., ConsoleLog console)
{
    //other constructor things
    cl = console;
}
public void beginTest(){
    testList[0].result = unprogrammedCurrent_test(.., ..); //this is an example of what the test looks like..
    cl.addToLog(TestList[0].result);
    ...//repeat for the rest of the test lists and tests..
    ...
    ...
}
```

The log will not update until all tests are done.

Comment: How and where are you calling the addToLog method? Please show us this code. You may be using the wrong instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code example is working fine!

> EDIT: There should be no need to force an empty dispatcher cycle like that, this is the equivalent of the old WinForms *Application.DoEvents()* there must be something else in your code that is blocking the dispatcher (UI thread), perhaps you should share an example of how your background worker is constructed and initiated.

I added a button to your form:

```
<Button Margin="0,267,376,0" Click="Button_Click" Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="142"/>
```

And the button click logic in the code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cl.addToLog(DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

[image: Runtime Capture 1]

> I suspect that you issue then is how you are calling addToLog() Most likely you are calling a different instance of the object to the one that is set as the data context.

I have modified your example to include a Background worker that is initiated from the form, this is working quite well:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (worker.IsBusy)
            worker.CancelAsync();
        else
        {
            cl.Text = String.Empty;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    public ConsoleLog cl { get; set; }
    private BackgroundWorker worker = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cl = new ConsoleLog();
        DataContext = cl;
        worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) => cl.addToLog($"{e.Result}");
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        while(true)
        {
            if ((sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending) break;
            cl.addToLog(DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(r.Next(500, 3000));
        }
        e.Result = "Stop" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

[image: Background worker output]

Comment: I have a class that calls upon tests on a device. This class performs multiple tests and adds each one to a log after every result is obtained. From the mainwindow class, I pass the ConsoleLog into the constructor of this Test class, could this be a possible issue?

Comment: Most likely, again without seeing the code this is all speculation... One of the main reasons to move to WPF was to make multi-threaded UI apps easier to write. It would be easier to have your test class raise events, BackgroundWorker is a good example where you can listen for progress events to pass notifications back to the calling thread. I can add an example of that if it helps?

Comment: I'll update my question to give a better idea on how it is being called soon.

Comment: I have updated my main post with a general idea of my use case

Comment: Yeah that's blocking code right there :) because cl is declared in the UI thread, and you are trying to access it inside the task... there are a few techniques to this, I'll put some together, no amount of changes to ConsoleLog needed.